# Laravel 4 model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got an easy (I guess it's easy) problem. I've created an new model called Player.php. It looks like this:

```
    <?php

    class Player extends Eloquent {


        protected $table = 'players';

        protected $fillable = array('char_name', 'sex');
        public $timestamps = false;

}
```

And I've used this in my controller:

```
public function post_character()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = array(
      'char_name' => 'required|unique:players,name|min:4',
      'sex' => 'required'
      );

    $validation = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validation->fails()) {
      return Redirect::to('create_character')->withErrors($validation);
    } else {

      $player = new Player;
      $player->name = $input['char_name'];
      $player->sex = $input['sex'];
      $player->save;

      return Redirect::to('managment')->with('success', 'Your character has been created.');
    }
}
```

This is my form:

```
@extends('base')
@section('main')

<div class="doc-content-box">
    <legend>Create a character</legend>
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'create_character')) }}

        <div class="control-group">
  {{ Form::label('char_name', 'Character name') }}
  <div class="controls">
    {{ Form::text('char_name', null, array('placeholder' => 'Character name goes here..')) }}
  </div>
</div>

   <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
{{ Form::select('sex', array('1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female'), '1'); }}
 </div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  {{ Form::submit('Create a character', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}
  {{ Form::button('Help', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
</div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>

@endsection
```

And now, this is my error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`thefs`.`players`, CONSTRAINT `players_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `players` (`name`, `sex`) values (?, ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'Malx', 1 => '1', ))
```

Also here's a screenshot of my database table 'players':

http://3.imgland.net/lL6EIv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error says that you have a constrain on players table. Here you create user:

```
  $player = new User;
  $player->name = $input['char_name'];
  $player->sex = $input['sex'];
  $player->save;
```

But you didn't set account_id. You may set this field NULL by default in phpmyadmin or delete foreign key constrain or set the right account_id

By the way you can write:

```
$player = Player::create(array(
    'name' => ...
));
```

instead of creating new object and then saving it

Comment: can I still use: `$player = new Player; $player->name = $input['char_name']; $player->sex = $input['sex']; $player->save;` I don't want it as null, how do I set the right account_id? I'm kind of newbie to all of this, I would like you to really explain me deeply haha

Comment: Just a word of advice, not that it's an enforced rule, but Laravel's auth stuff works better out of the box if you use "User" as the model name and "users" as the table name when doing account stuff (instead of "account" for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have in your model, a relation between accounts and players. You have to make this relation in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because you haven't defined relations between a user and a player in your Eloquent model. Here's a common way you could do it (note I'm replacing your "Account" model with "User" [and as such your accounts table would become a users table and the players table would have a foreign key of user_id instead of account_id], as it plays nicer with Laravel's default auth mechanism).

```
//user.php
class User extends Eloquent {
    //Define relation to players
    public function players() {
        return $this->hasMany('Player');
    }
}


//player.php
class Player extends Eloquent {
    //Your other player model code

    //Define relation to user 
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Now when creating a new player:

```
$player = new Player();
$player->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$player->name = $input['char_name'];
$player->sex = $input['sex'];
$player->save();
```

This assumes the user id is coming from whatever user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks! You have cleared my mind. Now, I'm needing a little more help.
How can I display let's say something like this (in a table):

http://1.imgland.net/8jWJcG.png

Display the character name (column 'name' in database), level ('level' in database), role('group_id' in database). To pull data out of the database and put it into a table? And how to view if it's online or offline ('online' in database)? 

And one more, how can I set the position of the player(it's for a game), to set default numbers in a column (posx, posy, posz) (and make it like a config to edit)?

Comment: You need to do a find on the model by some kind of criteria. Simple demo: http://d.chend.me/MoO5  This is really basic stuff though. Make sure to read the docs on retrieving Eloquent models. http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#introduction

Comment: Thanks and you didn't answer how can I setthe position of the player(it's for a game), to set default numbers in a column (posx, posy, posz) (and make it like a config to edit)?

Comment: As much as I'd love to be your personal code spewing robot all day, I would like you to at least attempt it yourself. Also, the Laravel documentation would answer almost all of these questions. Stop being lazy, and RTFM.

Comment: I've really took some time and it just won't work. I've tried multiple options, but I simply don't know how to do it. I'm not trying to be a beggar, but could you help me please?:)